# Supremum Norm Identity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

Let $f,g : [0,1] → \mathbb{R}$ be bounded functions. Prove that $ ∥fg∥  ≤  ∥f ∥∥g ∥$

Where we define the sup norm of a bounded function $f : D → \mathbb{R}$  as   $∥f∥ := sup${|f(x)| : x ∈ D}$ $.

Any ideas of where to start with this proof or theorems that are useful would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x \in [0,1];$

$|f(x)|\le \sup |f(x)|;$ $|g(x)|\le \sup |g(x)|;$

$|f(x)g(x)|=|f(x)| |g(x)|\le$

$ |f(x)| ||g|| \le ||f|| ||g||.$

$||f|| ||g||$ is an upper bound for $|f(x)g(x)|$.

$\sup |f(x)g(x)|$ is the smallest upper bound.

Hence

$||fg|| \le ||f||$ $||g||.$

Comment: sorry if I'm being stupid but how is $|f(x)g(x)| =|f(x)||g(x)| $.  Also how does $ |f(x)| $ differ from $||f||$

Comment: Absolute value:$ |ab|=|a| |b|$, example $|3(-4)|=|3||-4|=3(4)=12$; $|f(x)|\le \sup |f(x)|=||f||$, smallest upper bound for $|f(x)|.$

Comment: Of course, thank you.

Comment: Welcome. ok now?

Comment: Yes thank you !!

Comment: Do you know at all of any pairs of  bounded functions $f [0,1]→ \mathbb{R} $ where this inequality holds( that is $||fg||$ is not equal to $||f||||g||$

Comment: math2020. Take both f,g continuos on [0,1]. Let f be bell shaped starting for f(0)=0, maximum at x=1/4, say f(1/4)=2, then coming down and f(x) =0 for $x\ge 1/2$. g similar: g(x)= 0 for $x\le 1/2$, then has a peak at x=3/4, say f(3/4)=2, and comes down again. Here sup is maximum, since continuos. max (f(x)g(x))=0(ok?) and (max f(x))(max g(x))=4.ok?

Answer (score 1):

$$\|f \cdot g\|_\infty=\sup_{x\in D} |f(x) \cdot g(x)|= \sup_{x\in D}(|f(x)|| g(x)|)\leq \sup_{x\in D}( \|f\|_\infty\cdot |g(x)|) = \|f\|_\infty \cdot \|g\|_\infty$$